# How to transform custom AMSGrad.py into keras.optimizers.Optimizer?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

The AMSGrad.py is the following.
[AMSGrad.py](https://github.com/taki0112/AMSGrad-Tensorflow/blob/master/AMSGrad.py)

However, I have to transform them into keras.optimizer.Optimizer, in order to use them in the tensorflow model.compile()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code of a Keras optimizer you will see it has a subset of the functions of the AMSGrad.py optimizer. You could simply copy the
functions over in the correction section. Some adjustments may be needed.

However, why not simply use `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` with amsgrad=True?

Comment: Just different format, I have finished that, thx